# Convert JSON string to an array in multistep Form in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on dynamic multi step form .
**What I am doing :** 
1. creating input fields using AJAX 
2. taking input field info from user
3. serializeArray()
4. SUbmit (POST) : before submit convert input values into desired format ex: input `type=date` convert into utc format, which is working fine.

I have multi step format , in first step , I have two fields which has Student Number, Id  `type=list`(to create array) then click on next button and then I have second step form which has Name , date , address.
 I am converting date on submit using below code

```
var dateTypeField = $('form').find('input[type="date"]').attr('name');
        var dateField = $('form').find('input[type="date"]').val();
        var dateFormat = '';
if (dateField) {
                dateFormat = moment.utc(dateField).format('YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.SSSZ');
            }
            else {
                dateFormat = null;
            }
```

which is working fine .

**Question** :  I have two input fields in first step which has `type=list` , and value in string , I want to convert string into an array while clicking on submit. this is what I am doing

```
var listTypeField = $('form').find('input[type="list"]').attr('name');
            var inputTypeList = $('form').find('input[type="list"]').val();
            listTypeField = inputTypeList.split(',');
            var listFormat = inputTypeList.split(',');

            var formData = $form.serializeArray();

            formData.push({ name: dateTypeField, value: dateFormat });
            formData.push({ name: listTypeField, value: inputTypeList });
```

**Issue** : 1. I have two fields which has type= list , but showing only one field using `$('form').find('input[type="list"]').attr('name')`  2. spilt is undefined . 3. How to convert string into an array after serializeArray()? `formData.push({ name: listTypeField, value: inputTypeList });` not working for me. I want [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use switch case to solve this problem

```
                var name = input.getAttribute('name');
                var value;
                var type = input.dataset.type;
                switch (type) {
                    case "text":
                         value = input.value;
                        break;
                    case "list":
                         value = input.value.split(',');
                        break;
                    case "date":
                        value= input.value ? moment.utc(input.value).format('YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.SSSZ') : null;
                        break;
                }

                object[name] = value;
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all I don't know what is a ***input type="list"*** in HTML, maybe you have an ***input list***, in that case the selector should be simply **$('input[list]')**.

Second, if you have more than one input with the same type (eg. *[type="radio"]*) your approach will extract always the name from the last one:

```
<input type="radio" name="radio2" value="34" />
<input type="radio" name="radio7" value="45" />
// .......
console.log($('input[type="radio"]).length); /// 2
console.log($('input[type="radio"]).attr('name'); /// "radio7" --> Always the name from last element!
```

You have to list all your input[type="whatever"] and execute your code on every instance, something like this:

```
$('form').find('input[type="list"]').each(function() {
    /// This block will be executed on every instance
    var listTypeField = $(this).attr('name'); /// "this" is the current instance
    var inputTypeList = $(this).val();
    formData.push({ name: dateTypeField, value: inputTypeList.split(',') });
});
```

I hope this will help.